# Difference between learn with/from my major

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

> This summer, I sought to engage myself in experiences that I felt were
>   relevant to what I have been **learning with my art history major**.
>
> https://www.southwestern.edu/live/news/13558-curating-the-arts

What is the difference between “learn **with** my major” and “learn **from** my major”?  Are they interchangeable here?

Comment: It makes no difference to the meaning whether you use ***with*** or ***from***. Alternative prepositions which might be considered "acceptable" for this exact context include ***on, in, through***, and probably others. In short, it's not a context where there's a single "standard" preposition (though I suspect that in practice ***on*** is the most likely choice for most native speakers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One learns **from** a teacher, or a text, or a course of study, or some other source of knowledge. I suppose that a major in college/university study could be called a "course of study", but I would think a person really learns from the classwork, readings, and projects done during the process of that major.

"Learning with X" is a rather vague statement that the learning is in some way associated with X, but doesn't really indicate how. It is not wrong, but may well be unclear. It could include the same situation as "learning from X". It can also be used where X is a fellow-student, or a mentor.

I would perhaps recast the sentence as:

> This summer, I sought to engage myself in experiences that I felt were relevant to what I have been learning as I pursued my art history major.